# How to group GPUs in one node when using Slurm?

Tags: slurm

Situation : I have a 4 GPUs in 1 node, and I want to group 2 GPUs per each group.

Simply,

- node0 has gpu0, gpu1, gpu2, gpu3
- Group 1 : gpu0, gpu1
- Group 2 : gpu2, gpu3

Slurm provides [partition to group "nodes" into logical sets](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html), but partition is not for grouping inside node. If partition is not for this situation, could you suggest another logical concept for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group GPUs in Slurm using different name types in its definition inside /etc/slurm/gres.conf file. An example:

```
NodeName=node01[2-3] Name=gpu Type=gtx1060 File=/dev/nvidia[0-1] CPUs=0-7
NodeName=node01[2-3] Name=gpu Type=gtx1080 File=/dev/nvidia[2-3] CPUs=8-15
```

Select the GPU in the submit script using:

```
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:gtx1080:1
```